# Query with problem in the group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that works in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    r.*, c.*
FROM 
    Rsv AS r
INNER JOIN 
    Clts AS c ON r.ClientID = c.ClientID
LEFT OUTER 
    Mes AS m ON r.MesaID = m.MesaID
WHERE 
    RHS IS NULL AND RC = 0
GROUP BY 
    r.ClientID;
```

I want this to work in SQL Server and I know that in SQL Server when you use  `GROUP BY`, the elements in the `SELECT` need to be either in the `GROUP BY` or need to have an aggregate function. But I want to select more elements and I don't think I need aggregate functions on them because it doesn't matter which one it will retrieve the information from since only the `MesaNum` field is going to be different. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

**`Rsv` Table:**

```
RsvID    MesaID    ClientID    RsvTime      RsvDate    RHS    RC
    1         1           1       8:00   2018-09-17   null     0
    2         2           1       8:00   2018-09-17   null     0
    3         3           2       9:00   2018-09-17   null     0
```

Desired result:

```
RsvID    MesaID    ClientID    RsvTime     RsvDate    RHS    RC
    1       1,2           1       8:00   2018-09-17  null     0
    3         3           2       9:00   2018-09-17  null     0
```

(Sorry, couldn't figure out how to do tables here)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Using `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` simply makes no sense.  The query should be using aggregation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `STUFF` function to do `groupby_concat`, then make row number by `ClientID` get `rn = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT RsvID,ClientID,RsvTime,RsvDate,RHS,RC,
           STUFF((
              SELECT ',' + CAST(tt.MesaID AS VARCHAR(5))
              FROM Rsv tt
              WHERE tt.ClientID = t1.ClientID
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') MesaID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY RsvID) rn
    FROM Rsv t1
) t1
where rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f00d5362f2d3c144c102f640f8a4efb)

Comment: @HugoGaspar No problem glad to help